# Loading a MediaWiki webpage and then grabbing variables from it (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I am working on a Discord bot that works with MediaWiki wikis. I would like it to do two things: load a webpage and then grab some of the variables from it.

I am using JSDOM and Node.js to attempt to do so. This is my code:

```js
jsdom.JSDOM.fromURL(msg.content.split(" ")[1], {runScripts: "dangerously", resources: "usable", pretendToBeVisual: true}).then(function (dom, error) {
   d = dom.serialize();
   var $ = dom.window.$;
   var mw = dom.window.mw;
   if (!mw || (mw.config.get("wgNamespaceNumber") != 2 && mw.config.get("wgNamespaceNumber") != 3) || mw.config.get("wgTitle").includes("/")) {
       msg.reply(new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle("Error").setDescription("That is not a link to a wiki user or talk page.").setColor("RED"));
       return;
   } else {
       //continue doing whatever
   }
}
```

I am trying to check to see if the link that the user supplied in a command is actually a link to a MediaWiki wiki (more specifically a wiki user page). However, in the debugger, when I ask what the value of the `$` and `mw` variables are, it tells me that it is "undefined", even if I supply the bot with a link to a wiki user page, and it tells me that "That is not a link to a wiki user or talk page."

I would like to know how can I grab the `mw` and `$` variables from the MediaWiki page I load?

Comment: I don't use JSDom but you tell me... **(1)** What happens if you **don't**  name your variable as `$`? To me that's as bad naming it `var &&` or such, are you not confusing the parser here? (think JQuery or PHP variable declarations as examples). **(2)** Are you able to see _"the link that the user supplied"_ in anyway, like via doing `console.log( d );`? or try logging as `console.log( dom.window.mw );`

Comment: @VC.One **(1)** The `dom.window.$` is the JQuery that is present on the MediaWiki wiki installation, or so I think. However, this variable is undefined for one reason or another. **(2)** I do get the user input in the command line. However, it says `dom.window.mw` is undefined.

Comment: **(1)** Do you have an example of _"the MediaWiki page I load"_? I will check if properties `mw` and `$` exist on the page. **(2)** Since you want to check if user command has a link, tell me can you get access to their command (as text), if yes, then why not just use **String** functions to check if their command text contains an `https` and `wiki` as part of same link? Show an example text of command with a mediaWiki link and I'll show you how to extract the link using JS. Maybe you can later give such extracted link the Discord Bot...